# How to print with custom paper size in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm trying to print a document in my application. But on different printers i get different results. This is my code:

```
PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("My Envelope", 440, 630);
paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;

PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) => Console.Out.WriteLine("Printable Area for printer {0} = {1}", args.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, args.PageSettings.PrintableArea);

pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins   = new Margins(60, 40, 20, 20);

Console.Out.WriteLine("My paper size: " + pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize);

PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog(); // to choose printer
printDialog.Document = pd;

if (printDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize; // uncomment to override size from dialog

    Console.Out.WriteLine("Paper size for printer {0} = {1}", printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize);
    _sptTxtControl.Print(pd);
}
```

When dialog shows I have two printers - Samsung and HP. This is the console output for these two:

```
My paper size: [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Paper size for printer HP LaserJet 1022n = [PaperSize A4 Kind=A4 Height=1169 Width=827]
Printable Area for printer HP LaserJet 1022n = {X=21,83333,Y=15,66667,Width=789,3333,Height=1137,333}

My paper size: [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Paper size for printer Samsung SCX-4x28 Series PCL6 = [PaperSize A4 Kind=A4 Height=1169 Width=827]
Printable Area for printer Samsung SCX-4x28 Series PCL6 = {X=17,33333,Y=17,16667,Width=792,3333,Height=1135,167}
```

You can see that the dialog is changing the size to A4. So if you uncommemt line after showdialog I'm enforcing papersize. The output when printing looks like this:

```
My paper size: [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Paper size for printer HP LaserJet 1022n = [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Printable Area for printer HP LaserJet 1022n = {X=21,83333,Y=15,66667,Width=789,3333,Height=1137,333}

My paper size: [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Paper size for printer Samsung SCX-4x28 Series PCL6 = [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Printable Area for printer Samsung SCX-4x28 Series PCL6 = {X=16,66667,Y=20,Width=400,1667,Height=589,8333}
```

You can see that Samsung printer has good Printable Area while HP has not. HP has always  A4 size whatever I will change in code (set originatmargins etc.)

If I change my paper settings in print properties (sorry for Polish dialog):

[image: custom paper settings]

and not change paper size after showing dialog then HP is printing everything ok. Output looks like this:

```
My paper size: [PaperSize My Envelope Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Paper size for printer HP LaserJet 1022n = [PaperSize My Envelop Format Kind=Custom Height=630 Width=440]
Printable Area for printer HP LaserJet 1022n = {X=18,66667,Y=16,Width=405,3333,Height=597,3333}
```

But I don't want to force user to save custom size for his printer. I have tried also this with a Kyocera printer - it works, but for two other HP printers it doesn't.

And the worst part is that Word 2010 prints ok the same RTF document with this size on both printers, co I cant't blame the HP driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, I have changed my job ;)

Comment: Oops! Hope I won't have to do so also!!

Comment: @bizon hahahhaha, you made my day with this joke... :D

Answer (score 16):

After the PrintDialog closes, don't just set

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

Try also setting

```
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

I think that will take care of it.

Answer (score 4):

setting

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

and

```
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

might not work sometimes.

> The most appropriate thing is to select a custom papersize that is
>   installed in the Printers driver or Computer then setting the
>   properties of the following

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ExistingPaperSize;
pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ExistingPaperSize;
```

Like this code

```
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings = printdg.PrinterSettings;
    PaperSize RequiredPaperSize = CalculatePaperSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    bool FoundMatchingPaperSize = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; index++)
    {
         if (pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[index].Height == RequiredPaperSize.Height && pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[index].Width == RequiredPaperSize.Width)
          {
              pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[index];
              pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[index];
              FoundMatchingPaperSize = true;
              break;
           }
    }


    //Method to calculate PaperSize from Centimeter to 1/100 of an inch
 /// Caclulates the paper size
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WidthInCentimeters"></param>
    /// <param name="HeightInCentimetres"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize CalculatePaperSize(double WidthInCentimeters, 
        double HeightInCentimetres)
    {
        int Width = int.Parse( ( Math.Round ((WidthInCentimeters*0.393701) * 100, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) ).ToString() );
        int Height = int.Parse( ( Math.Round ((HeightInCentimetres*0.393701) * 100, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) ).ToString() );

        PaperSize NewSize = new PaperSize();
        NewSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
        NewSize.Width = Width;
        NewSize.Height = Height;
        NewSize.PaperName = "Letter";

        return NewSize;

    }
```

Comment: FYI this line is incorrect: `pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ExistingPaperSize;` because there is no property `pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSize`. Should be `pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize`.

Comment: Seems the latest updates to Windows 10 broke something with adding custom forms to the print manager. I had one I added previously that disappeared after the update, and even after re-adding it, the new form still doesn't show up in the PaperSizes collection. I didn't know I could just create the one I need on the fly though, so this solved my problem and saves having to mess with creating custom forms. Thanks!