# Why is print text cut off on the right when printing on legal format in landscape orientation?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, printing, remote-desktop

I have an application in C# that, among other things, prints various reports. When I access the application through **remote desktop** and I try to print in **legal** format from my application, text is cut off from the right. I have posted an [example PDF on my site](http://www.technoh.ca/cut_off_text.pdf).

When printing from any other application in landscape on legal paper the text is not cut off (for example, from Word or from another PDF file). The problem occurs only from my application.

Here is the code I use for the example PDF. The code for the application is much more complex but I believe that if I can fix the problem with the sample the solution should be the same for the application. Here is the code used to print:

```
printDocument.OriginAtMargins = false;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400);
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
printDocument.Print();
```

And the code inside the PrintPage event:

```
Graphics g = event_args.Graphics;
Font test_font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);

g.DrawString("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    test_font,
    System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
    new PointF(0, 0));

g.DrawString("-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+=-=+",
    test_font,
    System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
    new PointF(0, 10));
```

Note that the text **does not cut at the end of the page**, it cuts off at exactly 11.65 inches from the left (see the test PDF, it's really clear). I don't know why it's cutting off but I need the whole 14 inches available so any light you can shed on this mystery is most welcome.

**UPDATE**: Using the tests provided in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105972/how-to-print-with-custom-paper-size-in-winforms) (thank you Jongware), here are the paper sizes and printable area.

```
My paper size: [PaperSize Legal Kind = Custom Height=1400 Width=850]
Paper size for printer CutePD Writer (redirected 23) = [PaperSize custom Kind=Custom Height=1400 Width=850]
Printable Area for printer CutePD Writer (redirected 23) = {X=0,Y=0,Width=826,8333,Height=1169,333}
```

Now the fun thing is that if I try to print on the **server local** PDF writer, I get the following results:

```
My paper size: [PaperSize Legal Kind = Custom Height=1400 Width=850]
Paper size for printer CutePDF Writer = [PaperSize custom Kind=Custom Height=1400 Width=850]
Printable Area for printer CutePDF Writer = {X=0,Y=0,Width=850,Height=1400}
```

So it seems that when redirecting to a printer installed outside the remote desktop server it will use the printer's default (in this case, A4) without enforcing the currently selected paper size. This opens new avenues for investigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print with custom paper size in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105972/how-to-print-with-custom-paper-size-in-winforms)

Comment: That question does not relate to text being cut off, simply to paper sizes being different. The paper size I get with the same tests is the right one (e.g. Legal) but the text gets abruptly cut off.

Comment: Yes, therefore it may be your *printer driver* doesn't receive the correct page size.